# Could not determine JSON object type for type "Class"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got the following error while trying to add an object of type class to the **JArray**.

> Could not determine JSON object type for type "Class"

Here is my code:

```cs
private dynamic _JArray = null

private JArray NArray(Repository repository)
{
    _JArray = new JArray();

    string[] amounts = repository.Amounts.Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i <= amounts.Length; i++)
    {
        _JArray.Add(new AmountModel
                    {
                        Amounts = amounts[i],
                    });
    }

    return _JArray;
}

public class AmountModel
{
    public string Amounts;
}
```

Here's how I call it :

```cs
_JArray = NArray(repository);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_JArray));
```

How can I convert the **AmountModel (class)** inside of **_JArray (JArray)**, to be recognized by the system as JSON object?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `_JArray` dynamic?   All you ever seem to assign to it is a `JArray` so why not declare it as a `JArray`?

Comment: Hi @DStanley, after I change the `_JArray` from dynamic to `JArray`, the error still persists

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In order to add an arbitrary non-primitive POCO to a `JArray` (or `JObject`), you must explicitly serialize it, using one of the overloads of [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm):

```
_JArray = new JArray();

string[] amounts = repository.Amounts.Split('|');

for (int i = 0; i < amounts.Length; i++)
{
    _JArray.Add(JToken.FromObject(
        new AmountModel
        {
            Amounts = amounts[i],
        }));
}

return _JArray;
```

(Note also that I corrected the end condition in your `for` loop.  It was `i <= amounts.Length`, which resulted in an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.)

Working sample .Net fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMlYpn).

Alternatively, you could simplify your code with LINQ and [`JArray.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_FromObject.htm) by projecting the string array to an `AmountModel` enumerable then serializing the entire sequence to a `JArray` in one call:

```
var _JArray = JArray.FromObject(amounts.Select(a => new AmountModel { Amounts = a }));
```

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xQAPiA).

Comment: Thank you @dbc. It is working fine now, and thanks as well for the correction of the loop iteration. :D

Comment: @dbc Many, manyyyy hours of struggling with this - your LINQ expression helped immensely. Thank you

Comment: because i am happy and you now it

Comment: what is the purpose of the JArrat constructor `JArray(params object[] content)` then ?

Comment: @kofifus - From the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JArray.cs#L77) it just calls the `new JArray(object)` constructor.  `content` can contain `JToken` objects or primitive objects that are convertible to `JValue`, such as `string` or `int`, as well as collections of such.  I.e. `new JArray("hello", "there")`.  But LINQ to JSON will not invoke the **serializer** for non-primitive types, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Works like a charm :)