# How To Create a JSON Object within an Existing Object in JSON using JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to edit an existing Json File that contains an object called "forge" ("forge" itself is contained within an object called "profiles"), and within that object, I am trying to add another object called resolution that contains height and width. The native application it belongs to can modify and add this element, but I can only seem to be able to read, and write/create all other objects within the forge object except the resolution object and its children.

[image: What it should look like, (circled x indicates what I cannot get render)]

But no matter how much I read in newtonsoft documentation, nothing appears to be working. This is what I have written so far. Note that this method is just for overwriting all the contents in the "forge" object, and I tired to add the resolution object, but it fails. Anyone know how to do this? (Connection path is the json file)

[image: My Method]

Comment: I should mention, that if that JArray stuff was not there, then it runs fine and overwrites the forge object correctly.

Comment: @MickyD Would that be more useful? Many tutorials I've seen and read suggest doing it in this fashion, I'm not in love with this so I could create a class to do it, So you are saying the following: Create an object (class) with everything in it, and then instead jsonObj["profiles"]["forge"] = mycreatedclass;  then serialize it?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: To add an arbitrary POCO to a `JObject` or `JArray` you need to serialize it with some overload of `JToken.FromObject`.  See [Could not determine JSON object type for type “Class”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728452/3744182) for example.  But I agree that using `JObject` here seems like an antipattern, which not just serialize an anonymous object?

Comment: Oh you're reading from some serive, nevermind

Answer (score 1):

I think the "resolution" is not array, but an object.

Try this

```
    dynamic forge = new JObject();
    forge.Name = "forge";
    forge.Type = "Brasil";

    dynamic resolutionObj = new JObject();

    resolutionObj.Width = "10";
    resolutionObj.Height = "100"; 

    forge.resolution = resolutionObj;
```

You will see anything like this:

```
{
  "Name": "forge",
  "Type": "Brasil",
  "resolution": {
    "Width": "10",
    "Height": "100"
  }
}
```